# How to format a value with a single decimal place using C#

Tags: c#, string, format, decimal

I need to convert some value into decimal. i have done with the below:

```
    Double calculateinputPower="somegivenvalue";
       String valuePower="somevalue";
       Double calculatePower = Double.Parse(valuePower);
       calculatePower = calculatePower - calculateinputPower + calculateErp * 1;
       calculatePower = Double.Parse(String.Format("{0:0.0}", calculatePower));
       valuePower = System.Convert.ToString(calculatePower);
       ERP.Text = valuePower;
```

if my output value is like 
    ex:66.2356 -> 66.2 , 32.568 -> 32.5 , 22.35264 ->22.3
    i am getting the format which i need exactly but if the output value is like
    22,33,11,66,55 something like this then i want convert that value to 
    22->22.0
    33->33.0
    11->11.0
    66->66.0 how can i get this in C#.

i used `myVal.ToString("F");` then i am getting 0.00
if i use `ToString("N2");` then i am getting 1,000.00
but i don't want money format or 0.00 format 
What exactly i need is single .0 if the value is non decimal.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `.ToString("0.0")` (Note this uses rounding so `22.26 -> 22.3`)

```
     double i = 22.23;
     double j = 45;

     string si = i.ToString("0.0"); //22.2 
     string sj = j.ToString("0.0"); //45.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try in this way:

```
valuePower = calculatePower.ToString("F1");
```

To learn more, follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the [documentation for the format strings you're using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

You've tried `F`, which says as you've not specified the precision that the *"Default precision specifier: Defined by NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits."*, which is 2 in your case.

You've tried `N2`, which says that the 2 is the *"Precision specifier: Desired number of decimal places."*.

As you only want a single decimal place, use `F1` or `N1`, depending on your formatting requirements.

```
var number1 = 66.2356d;
var number2 = 66d;

var string1 = number1.ToString("N1"); // 66.2
var string2 = number2.ToString("N1"); // 66.0
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0KCkdd).